# Linked list C segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a linked list in C, but i get a segmentation fault?
i just defined the structure then made a simple function to create a single node and assign the value to it , then a function called append to add a node at the end of the list, the main program takes input and append the list and finally it prints the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
  int value ;
  struct list *next ;
}node;

node* create(int value, node *next)
{
  //creating node and allocating memory
  node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  //assigning values to the node
  new_node->value = value ;
  new_node->next = next ;

  return new_node;
}
node* append(int value,node *head){
  //creating the node
  node* new_node = create(value,NULL);
  //handling the case in which the head is NULL, other words when we don't have a previous node to append to
  if (head == NULL) {
    head = new_node;
    return head;
  }
  //the standard procesdure
  else{
  //traversing the list
  node* cursor = head ;
  while (cursor != NULL) {
    cursor = cursor->next ;
  }
  // appending the node to the list
  cursor->next = new_node;
  return head;
}
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int n ;
  printf("Enter the length of the list you wish to make\n");
  scanf("%d",&n );
  node* head = NULL;
  while (n--) {
    int value;
    printf("enter the value of the %d node\n",n);
    scanf("%d",&value);
    head = append(value,head);
  }
  //printing the list 
  node* cursor = head ;
  while (cursor !=NULL) {
    printf("%d\n",cursor->value );
    cursor = cursor->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (cursor != NULL) {
    cursor = cursor->next ;
}
// appending the node to the list
cursor->next = new_node;
```

*cursor* will be NULL after your while-loop. Instead do this:

```
while (cursor->next != NULL) {
    cursor = cursor->next ;
}
// appending the node to the list
cursor->next = new_node;
```